# Как сделать слияние таблиц в рекурсивном запросе?

Tags: sql, oracle

Дано три таблицы:

```
--Таблица каталога продуктов
create table catalog (cid number primary key, -- id раздела
par_cid number references catalog, -- ссылка на родительский раздел
rname varchar2(400), -- наименование раздела
rdescr varchar2(4000), -- описание
rcdate date -- дата создания
);

--Таблица продуктов
create table products (pid number primary key, -- id продукта
rcid number references catalog, -- ссылка на каталог
pname varchar2(500), -- наименование продукта
pdescr varchar2(4000), -- спецификация
punit number references units, -- единица измерения
pper number references persons -- ответственный
);

--Таблица движения продуктов
create table records (rpid number references products, -- продукт
rdate date, -- дата операции
incoming varchar2(2) default '1', -- поступление '1', расход '0'
quantity number, -- количество
rate number -- цена в рублях
);
```

Требуется написать sql запрос для вывода примерно в таком виде:

```
<Наименование раздела каталога уровня1> || Поступление. Руб. || Расход. Руб
...
<Наименование раздела каталога уровня(K-1)> || Поступление. Руб. || Расход. Руб
<Наименование раздела каталога уровня(K)> || Поступление. Руб. || Расход. Руб
<Наименование Продукта1 этого раздела> || Поступление. Руб. || Расход. Руб || Поступление. Количество || Расход. Количество || Остаток
...
<Наименование ПродуктаN этого раздела> || Поступление. Руб. || Расход. Руб || Поступление. Количество || Расход. Количество || Остаток
<Наименование раздела каталога уровня(K)> || Поступление. Руб. || Расход. Руб
<Наименование Продукта1 этого раздела> || Поступление. Руб. || Расход. Руб || Поступление. Количество || Расход. Количество || Остаток
...
<Наименование ПродуктаN этого раздела> || Поступление. Руб. || Расход. Руб || Поступление. Количество || Расход. Количество || Остаток
<Наименование раздела каталога уровня1> || Поступление. Руб. || Расход. Руб
... и так далее аналогично

Расчет для разделов должен выполняться в соответствии с иерархией. Количество уровней иерархии не ограничено.
```

Я написал следующий код для создания недостающих таблиц и заполнения всех таблиц данными:

```
--units - Таблица "единиц измерения"
CREATE TABLE units (
    Id number GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,     --Идентификатор units (Автоматическая нумерация, первичный ключ)
    Unit varchar2(150) NOT NULL                                 --Название units
);

--Persons - Таблица "Сотрудники"
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Id number GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,     --Идентификатор сотрудника (Автоматическая нумерация, первичный ключ)
    Name varchar2(150) NOT NULL                                 --ФИО сотрудника
);

--Данные Persons - Таблица "Сотрудники"
begin
INSERT INTO Persons (Name) values ('Иванов И. Г.');
INSERT INTO Persons (Name) values ('Смолин А. С.');
INSERT INTO Persons (Name) values ('Панасенко С. Н.');
INSERT INTO Persons (Name) values ('Поповский М. Ф.');
INSERT INTO Persons (Name) values ('Васильев М. С.');
INSERT INTO Persons (Name) values ('Ткаченко И. В.');
end;

--Данные units - Таблица "единиц измерения"
INSERT INTO units (Unit) values ('Шт.');

--Данные catalog - Таблица каталога продуктов
begin
insert into catalog values (1, NULL, 'Каталог', 'Описание Каталог', TIMESTAMP '2021-01-20 7:55:00');

insert into catalog values (2, 1, 'Стройматериалы', 'Описание Стройматериалы', TIMESTAMP '2021-01-21 7:55:00');
insert into catalog values (3, 1, 'Сантехника', 'Описание Сантехника', TIMESTAMP '2021-01-22 7:55:00');
insert into catalog values (4, 1, 'Электротовары ', 'Описание Электротовары', TIMESTAMP '2021-01-23 7:55:00');
begin
insert into catalog values (5, 2, 'Штукатурки', 'Описание Штукатурки', TIMESTAMP '2021-01-24 7:55:00');
insert into catalog values (6, 2, 'Грунтовки', 'Описание Грунтовки', TIMESTAMP '2021-01-25 7:55:00');

insert into catalog values (7, 3, 'Ванны ', 'Описание Ванны', TIMESTAMP '2021-01-26 7:55:00');
insert into catalog values (8, 3, 'Унитазы', 'Описание Унитазы', TIMESTAMP '2021-01-27 7:55:00');

insert into catalog values (9, 4, 'Удлинители', 'Описание Удлинители', TIMESTAMP '2021-01-28 7:55:00');
insert into catalog values (10, 4, 'Инструменты', 'Описание Инструменты', TIMESTAMP '2021-01-29 7:55:00');
end;

--Данные products - Таблица продуктов
begin
insert into products values (1, 5, 'Штукатурка1', 'Спецификация Штукатурка1', 1, 1);
insert into products values (2, 5, 'Штукатурка2', 'Спецификация Штукатурка2', 1, 2);

insert into products values (3, 6, 'Грунтовка1', 'Спецификация Грунтовка1', 1, 3);
insert into products values (4, 6, 'Грунтовка2', 'Спецификация Грунтовка2', 1, 4);

insert into products values (5, 7, 'Ванна1', 'Спецификация Ванна1', 1, 5);
insert into products values (6, 7, 'Ванна2', 'Спецификация Ванна2', 1, 6);

insert into products values (7, 8, 'Унитаз1', 'Спецификация Унитаз1', 1, 1);
insert into products values (8, 8, 'Унитаз2', 'Спецификация Унитаз2', 1, 2);

insert into products values (9, 9, 'Удлинитель1', 'Спецификация Удлинитель1', 1, 3);
insert into products values (10, 9, 'Удлинитель2', 'Спецификация Удлинитель2', 1, 4);

insert into products values (11, 10, 'Инструмент1', 'Спецификация Инструмент1', 1, 5);
insert into products values (12, 10, 'Инструмент2', 'Спецификация Инструмент2', 1, 6);
end;
```

Вывел все каталоги:

```
SELECT cid, par_cid, rname
FROM catalog
START WITH par_cid is null
CONNECT BY PRIOR cid = par_cid
ORDER BY cid;
```

Глубже в рекурсию не знаю, как написать запрос. Можете подсказать, как дальше?

Comment: _Глубже в рекурсию не знаю_, ну глубже и не надо вроде. А что конкретно вам дальше не понятно? Соединить таблицы не можете, или что-то ещё?

Comment: Да, не получается присоединить таблицы в последнем запросе...

Comment: Покажите как пробовали, что не получилось. Ваш вопрос  состоит из одного задания и включает в себя несколько подвопросов.

Comment: Проблема в соединении 3-х таблиц в CONNECT BY:
SELECT level, cid, par_cid, rname
FROM catalog inner join products on catalog.cid = products.rcid
inner join records on products.pid = records.rpid
START WITH par_cid is null
CONNECT BY PRIOR cid = par_cid
ORDER BY cid;

Ошибка - "no data found"

Comment: Ну если у вас [нет данных](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a60fa9f119848ebd11b4bd00289f314a), то всё правильно, ничего не найдёт. **PS** Правте вопрос, избегайте комментариев, а если комментарий, то указывaйте ссылку на db<>fiddle, как показал выше.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал про db<>fiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B_%D0%B2_SQL) случаем не то, что вам нужно?

```sql
with rec as (
  select
    pr.pid,
    null as cid,
    pr.rcid as par_cid,
    pr.pname as name,
    sum(case when incoming = '1' then rec.quantity*rec.rate end) incoming_money,
    sum(case when incoming = '0' then rec.quantity*rec.rate end) outcoming_money,
    sum(case when incoming = '1' then rec.quantity end) incoming,
    sum(case when incoming = '0' then rec.quantity end) outcoming,
    sum(case when incoming = '1' then 1 else -1 end * rec.quantity) balance
  from
    products pr
    inner join records rec on rec.rpid=pr.pid
  where
  ...
  group by 
    pr.pid,
    pr.rcid,
    pr.pname
  union all select
    null,
    cat.cid,
    cat.par_cid,
    cat.rname,
    incoming_money,
    outcoming_money,
    incoming,
    outcoming,
    balance
  from
    rec
    inner join catalog cat on cat.cid = rec.par_cid)
select
  pid,
  cid,
  name,
  sum(incoming_money),
  sum(outcoming_money),
  sum(incoming),
  sum(outcoming),
  sum(balance)
from
  rec
group by
  pid,
  cid,
  name
```

Comment: Подкорректировал код под себя, убрал "where
  ...", после запуска Oracle выдал ошибку "ORA-32039: recursive WITH clause must have column alias list". Добавил список алиасов: rec(pr.pid,cid,par_cid,name,incoming,outcoming,balance). Ошибка "ORA-02000: missing ) keyword" ((

Comment: Где-то скобку потеряли.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9a5f9ab06bffa3d769681c0b23a3ddb7

Comment: спасибо, очень помогли)